# Почему Host.CreateApplicationBuilder из ASP.NET Core не находит appsettings.json?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Cоздаю приложение с помощью ASP.NET Core 7. Но не могу понять, почему я не могу получить значения из `appsettings.json`? `loggingEnv` почему-то пустой. Хотя [документация](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.host.createapplicationbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) говорит, что `appsettings.json` загружается автоматически из текущей директории.

`appsettings.json` находится в той же директории, что и `Program.cs`. Пробовал еще переносить `appsettings.json` в `/Properties`, но тоже не помогает.

Если при запуске кода поставить брейкпоинт, то `builder.Environment.ContentRootPath` будет равен `...ProjectFolder\bin\Debug\net7.0`, но разве так должно быть? Разве он не должен быть просто `...ProjectFolder`?

`Program.cs`

```
var builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder();

var loggingEnv = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Logging").GetChildren();

var app = builder.Build();

app.Run();
```

`appsettings.json`

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    },
    "File": {
      "Path": "Temp/app.log",
      "Append": true,
      "MinLevel": "Information",
      "FileSizeLimitBytes": 0,
      "MaxRollingFiles": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в `builder.Environment.ContentRootPath`. Он `...ProjectFolder\bin\Debug\net7.0` вместо `...ProjectFolder`. Сейчас просто задал директорию вот так:

```
var builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder();

var projectPath = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())?.Parent?.Parent?.FullName;
ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(projectPath);

builder.Configuration.SetBasePath(projectPath);
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("Properties/appsettings.json", true, true);

var app = builder.Build();

app.Run();
```

Но странно почему пришлось это делать, потому что есть другой проект, в котором всё работает без этого (работает как в вопросе).

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать (﻿using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration):

```cs
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                 .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", true, true);
```

Также можно использовать (using System.Text.Json.Serialization):

```
 builder.Services.AddControllers()
                .AddJsonOptions(o => o.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles);
```

Привел пример для ASP.NET Core и Console App.

Comment: Оба варианта не подошли, appsettings всё еще не загружается

Comment: Можете показать структуру проекта?

Стоит ли свойство у `appsettings.json` "Копировать в выходной каталог": "Копировать более позднюю версию" и свойство "Действие при сборке": "Содержимое"?